# Make a frame to an image in python

Tags: python, image

Images are represented as matrices. Is there a practical way to make sort of frame around the content of the image? (in a monoton color)

Comment: Can you give more context? Are you asking how to make a new larger matrix and center the contents of another matrix in it?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot of ways to do that. I think the easiest way is just to add an image with everything transparent except for the borders and then draw it on top of the screen every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Like Miguel Pereira says, the easiest way is paste a frame previously made in the image that you want set the frame. You can use PIL like this.

```
from PIL import Image

img_frame = Image.open("frame_name.png")
img_bg = Image.open("bg_name.png")

img_bg.paste(img_frame, (cord_x, cord_y))

img_bg.show()
```

You may need to resize one of the images to fit

Comment: is there a way to represent the image as a tensor and then apply some kind of manipulation?

Comment: after paste the second image to the first image, you can use numpy for manipulate the result image, numpy is more direct library to manipulate the image, PIL in that case is very limit to its functions